# JSON To Features tool does not obey symbology?

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, modelbuilder, symbology, json

I am using the **JSON to features** tool in the ArcMap conversion toolbox and i cannot seem to get the symbology right.

This JSON i am using is a GPFeatureRecordSetLayer which i have written to a .json file

```
{
    "displayFieldName": "pointFeature",
    "hasM": false,
    "hasZ": false,
    "geometryType": "esriGeometryPoint",
    "spatialReference": {
        "wkid": 102100,
        "latestWkid": 3857
    },
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "OBJECTID",
            "type": "esriFieldTypeOID",
            "alias": "OBJECTID"
        },
        ...
    ],
    "features": [
        {
            "geometry": {
                "type": "point",
                "x": 19865753.933378372,
                "y": -2051854.6857393598,
                "spatialReference": {
                    "wkid": 102100,
                    "latestWkid": 3857
                }
            },
            "symbol": {
                "color": {
                    "r": 0,
                    "g": 0,
                    "b": 0,
                    "a": 0.001176470588235294
                },
                "size": 13.333333333333332,
                "type": "simplemarkersymbol",
                "style": "circle",
                "outline": {
                    "color": {
                        "r": 0,
                        "g": 255,
                        "b": 255,
                        "a": 1
                    },
                    "width": 2.6666666666666665,
                    "type": "simplelinesymbol",
                    "style": "solid"
                },
                "xoffset": 0,
                "yoffset": 0
            },
            "attributes": {
                "OBJECTID": "4131",
                ...

            }
        }
    ],
    "exceededTransferLimit": true
}
```

When i run the **Features to JSON** tool on the generated features i get this JSON string which totally skips any symbology information.

```
{
    "displayFieldName": "pointFeatures",
    "fieldAliases": {
        "OBJECTID": "OBJECTID"
    },
    "geometryType": "esriGeometryPoint",
    "spatialReference": {
        "wkid": 102100,
        "latestWkid": 3587
    },
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "OBJECTID",
            "type": "esriFieldTypeOID",
            "alias": "OBJECTID"
        },
        ...
    ],
    "features": [
        {
            "attributes": {
                "OBJECTID": "4131",
                ...
            },
            "geometry": {
                "x": 19865753.933378372,
                "y": -2051854.6857393598
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Everything else works fine. Is this a known limitation?

Comment: I am using this as part of a GP service and the step after converting from **json to features**, using the model builder, is **layer to kml**, where all my features are barely visible because they dont have any symbology. 

Should i mark this as answered simply because the help for the **json to features** tool only says it can be used to set attribute and geometry data and does not mention the ability to set any other attributes of a feature or graphic?

Comment: correct.  it doesnt do symbology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i will mark this as answered simply because the **json to features** tool only says it can be used to set attribute and geometry data and does not mention the ability to set any other attributes of a feature or graphic.